# If I create a new set of roles in a developer sandbox will the role ids be the same when I push them to another environment?

Tags: salesforce-id, role-hierarchy

I can't test this myself, as I don't have access the other side of the deployment connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they will not. How are you using the id's in Apex? If so, you'll want to reference the roles by DeveloperName, which will remain consistent across deployments.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Tim. I hear they will stay the same if they are cloned. However, is this the case if the profiles are in a change set? Does Salesforce clone the profiles? Or I seem to remember it is not possible to push profiles via change sets?

Comment: Hi Paul, by "cloned" do you mean refreshed from production into the sandbox? If so, then yes the ids would be consistent. However, is it still best practice to not reference the ids statically (it that's the intention).